# Trying to compare if the region has image a or b with pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui, rpa

I´m trying to use pyautogui for automation log in in desktop app, but sometimes the region has  blue button and sometimes is white button.
In the first moment , i have to wait the app to open. I don´t want to use pyautogui.sleep(), because is not fast .
I´ve tried to compare with "if" or using "while" to get the position , but something is wrong and i dónt know how to fix this errors. Could you help me ?

```
title = "Title.PNG"
bluebutton= 'bluebutton.png'
whitebutton='whitebutton.png'
while (location == None):
    try:
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(title)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
while (button1 == None) or (button == None):
    button = button()
    button1 = button_white()
if button1 is None:
    buttonX = button
else:
    buttonX = button1
pyautogui.click(buttonX)


def button():
    global button5
    while (button5 == None):
        try:
            button5 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(bluebutton)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return button5


def button_white():
    global button5
    while (button5 == None):
        try:
            button5 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(whitebutton)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return button5
```

Comment: Do you just want to see if the color is blue or white?

Comment: I was triyng it. The program is IB API, but i figured out one API called ib_sync who can help more.

Comment: I get it, but my question is: what is your main goal? If the coordinates is blue do something or if it is white do another?

Comment: Yes, but the coordinates can change in this software. That´s why I was using images to compare if there was a blue button or red button.  The better if you gonna use pyautogui with IB API ,is to comparing two images, but if you don´t have this first image in function, you lost all program in the case.